# Visual Studio Online Hosted Agent Public IP

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm attempting to move our internal builds to VSO. The kicker is that we have our own private nuget feeds that the builds will obviously need access to. Now I would rather not have to just open the feeds up to everyone and instead whitelist the ip(s) being used by the VSO hosted build agents.

Has anyone got any ideas as to how I go about getting th ip ranges used by these hosted agents?

Or is there a better way of achieving what I am after?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

VSO Build Agents are hosteded in cloud, so there is no changeless IP range for them.

I would recommend you set a credential for your Nuget Server. And in the build definition, adding a powershell step to call Nuget restore instead of using the "Restore Nuget Packages" option provide by VSO.

Answer (score 0):

Other option also might to be install your own agent service on machine which has access to yours Nuget Repo:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows